# How to get LaTeX to output UTF8-characters in the command line?

Tags: input-encodings, console

For a script, I want to get the hyphenation that LaTeX chooses, including my custom hyphenations file.

I use this code and it works mostly:

```
echo "\\\documentclass{standalone}
\\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\\\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\\\input{headers/hyphenation.tex}
\\\showhyphens{Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit}" | pdflatex | grep -a "T1/cmr/m/n/10" | sed -e 's/.*T1\/cmr\/m\/n\/10\s*//'
```

With most stuff, this works and only gives me the hyphenated version of that word. But when the word in `\showhyphens` contains things like umlauts, it replaces them with the UTF8 replacement character.

This does not occur if I do not pipe it into `(pdf)LaTeX`, so I guess the characters are properly submitted to LaTeX. But LaTeX cannot properly output them to the console.

How to get LaTeX to properly show this instead of

```
Nah-rungs-mit-te-lun-ver-tr�g-lich-keit
```

?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unicode characters a bit complicated for TeX, have you tried one of the Unicode engines XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: three backslashes  in the echo?

Comment: if I replace `\\\ ` by `\\ ` then your example gives an error that headers/hyphenation.tex is not found. please provide an example that may be run to debug the issue.

Comment: If I change my terminal encoding to UTF-8 I at least can get XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX to show the right thing in the output. (Again Windows 10, cmd terminal, MikTeX binaries.)

Comment: @moewe I wonder, if that makes any difference on unixoid operating systems..

Comment: @moewe the data in the log and the terminal is the same, but probably when you look at the log file your editor makes a better guess of the 8-bit encoding than if you stream the same data to a utf-8 terminal.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed. I must have been confused about the `.log` file. When I just tested it now the `pdflatex` `.log` was also mangled as expected, so I must have looked at the XeLaTex or LuaLaTeX log. I deleted the comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 7):

Hyphenation in TeX is (unfortunately) tied to the *font* encoding. You are using `T1`. `\showoutput` is showing the internal box representation of the characters so the fact that your input was `utf-8` or even that it was `ä` is long gone. The internal `T1` encoding that is being displayed has some resemblance to `latin-1` but none at all to `UTF-8`, and this box logging is built in to the engine and not customisable by a macro layer such as `latex`.

LaTeX can output `utf8` on the terminal via

```
\typeout{\detokenize{Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit}}
```

but that is outputting something completely different, the input character tokens, not an internal box representation.

---

If I change your script to

```
echo "\\documentclass{standalone}
\\usepackage[$1]{fontenc}
%\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\\input{headers/hyphenation.tex}
\\showhyphens{Nahrungsmittelunverträglichkeit}" | $2
```

Then

```
. test OT1 pdflatex
```

produces

```
[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Nah-rungs-mit-te-lun-vertr^^?aglichkeit
```

and

```
. test T1 pdflatex
```

produces

```
[] \T1/cmr/m/n/10 Nah-rungs-mit-te-lun-ver-tr�g-lich-keit
```

and

```
. test TU xelatex
```

produces

```
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Nah-rungs-mit-te-lun-ver-träg-lich-keit
```

So you see three different internal representations of the same input, the `xetex` one is essentially the unicode text so displays naturally.

Comment: what if you replace `ä` with `\"a` during read of input?

Comment: @naphaneal it makes no difference, inputenc expands `ä` to `\"{a}` so entering `\"{a}` just saves some expansion steps but the box representation shown by `\showhyphens` is not affected.